# How to read a specific integer from a csv file using bash script?

Tags: linux

I have written a bash script (below) to add data to a csv file, now I want to read a specific integer from this csv file. How can i do it?

I used the 'cat' command but it opens the whole file.But i don't want that, i want to open, for example a customer with id number 1.

On the other hand how to update the files in a csv file as well. For instance, the customer name is save as 'John' in csv file. By using the update function, I want to change his name to 'Mattew Moniz'. How can i do this?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Final Project 

while :
do

clear

echo "          ITC 350-Open Source Software Project "
echo ""
echo " ==================================================="
echo "    Customer Account Banking System          "
echo " ==================================================="

echo -e "\e[31m1) Create a new customer account\e[0m"       #red
echo -e "\e[32m2) Update account data\e[0m"                 #green
echo -e "\e[33m3) View and manage transaction\e[0m"         #orange
echo -e "\e[34m4) Check customers account details\e[0m"     #blue
echo "5) Delete customer's account"
echo -e "\e[36m6) Exit\e[0m"                                #gray
echo ""
echo ""
echo -e "\e[32mPlease choose an option:\e[1m"               #ligh green 
read usr_cmd

clear

case $usr_cmd in 

1) echo "Enter customer name: "
read cus_name
while ! [[ $cus_name =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_name =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid name"
    read cus_name
done


echo "Enter customer DOB: "
read cus_dob


echo "Enter customer national ID number: "
read cus_national_num

while ! [[ $cus_national_num =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer national ID number "
    read cus_national_num
done

echo "Enter customer email address: "
read cus_email

echo "Enter cutomer city: "
read cus_city

while ! [[ $cus_city =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_city =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid city"
    read cus_city
done

echo "Enter customer country : "
read cus_country

while ! [[ $cus_country =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_country =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid country "
    read cus_country
done


echo "Enter contact number: "
read cus_phone_num

while ! [[ $cus_phone_num =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer contact number "
    read cus_phone_num
done

echo "Enter type of the account (Saving/Current): "
read cus_account_type


echo "Enter first deposit amount : "
read cus_first_deposit 

while ! [[ $cus_first_deposit =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer first deposit amount "
    read cus_first_deposit
done

;;
# For this part I must write the code to generate a unique customer reg. number automatically
2) echo "Enter the customer registration number to update account data:  "
read cus_reg_num

echo "Enter customer name: "
read cus_name

while ! [[ $cus_name =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_name =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid name"
    read cus_name
done

echo "Enter customer DOB: "
read cus_dob

echo "Enter customer national ID number: "
read cus_national_num

while ! [[ $cus_national_num =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer national ID number "
    read cus_national_num
done

echo "Enter customer email address: "
read cus_email

echo "Enter customer city: "
read cus_city

while ! [[ $cus_city =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_city =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid city"
    read cus_city
done


echo "Enter customer country: "
read cus_country

while ! [[ $cus_country =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_country =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid country "
    read cus_country
done

echo "Enter customer contact number: "
read cus_phone_num

while ! [[ $cus_phone_num =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer contact number "
    read cus_phone_num
done


echo "Enter type of the account (Saving/Current): "
read cus_account_type

while ! [[ $cus_country =~ ^-?[[:alpha:]]+$ || $cus_country =~ " " ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid account type "
    read cus_country
done

echo "Enter first deposit amount: "
read cus_first_deposit

while ! [[ $cus_phone_num =~ ^-?[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; do
    echo "Please enter a valid customer first depsit amount: "
    read cus_phone_num
done


;;

#I must write the code to bring changes to the customer's money from csv file
3) echo "Which operation would you like to process with: "

echo "1) Deposit"
read cus_deposit_to_account

echo "2) Withdraw"
read cus_withdraw


;;

#I must write the code to get the data from FINAL_PROJECT.cvs file and display it
4) echo "Enter the customer's registration number to view details: "
read view_cus_reg_num


;;

#I must write the code to delete the customer from FINAL_PROJECT.csv
5) echo "Enter the customer's registration number to delete: "
read cus_reg_num

;;


6)break;;
*) echo "Invalid option";;
esac

echo "Press 6 to quit, anything else to continue: " 
read confirm_exit 
if [ $confirm_exit -eq 6 ]
then break
fi
done



echo "Customer Name", "Customer DOB", "Customer National ID Number", "Customer Email Address", "Customer City", "Customer Country", "Customer Contact Number", "Customer Account Type", "Customer First Deposit Amount" >> FINAL_PROJECT.csv

echo "$cus_name", "$cus_dob", "$cus_national_num", "$cus_email", "$cus_city", "$cus_country", "$cus_phone_num", "$cus_account_type", "$cus_first_deposit" >> FINAL_PROJECT.csv

#awk '!x[$1]++ && ! /^[[:blank:]]*$/' OSSGrades.csv

grep . FINAL_PROJECT.csv | awk '!a[$1]++' >> FINAL_PROJECT.csv
```

Comment: I think you should reduce things to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To find id 1 in the third column, you can use `grep`:

```
grep '^\([^,]*, \)\{2\}1,' file.csv
```

- `^` matches the beginning of line;
- `[^,]` matches any character except for a comma;
- `*` means *zero or more times*, so `[^,]*` matches zero or more non-commas;
- `\(...\)` is used here just to group a "column";
- `\{2\}` says that the previous element (the group mentioned above) must be repeated twice, i.e. the id is preceded by two columns.

Note that this only works for simple CSV files. For real ones, which can contain quoted or escaped commas or even newlines inside the cells, you'll need a real programming language instead of the shell.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work. 

grep '^\([^,]*,\)\{2\}1,' FINAL_PROJECT.csv

Comment: Also, if you have tried my code you can that everything is saved twice in my csv file.
Can you please write a code to just save everything one time in csv file.

Comment: @Nikola: Are you sure there's a customer with ID "1"?

Comment: Also, I noticed you have spaces after the commas. Command updated.